# Hive Class Not found

Tags: class, hadoop, jar, hive, classnotfoundexception

I have a jar named "myudfs.jar" that contains a class "MyUpper.java"
In the hive interpreter, I added it with:
`add jar myudfs.jar` and I had no problem:

```
Added myudfs.jar to class path
Added resource: myudfs.jar
```

Unfortunately, when I run under Hive the following command:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION myUpper AS 'org/hue/udf/MyUpper.java';
```

I have an error:

```
FAILED: Class org/hue/udf/MyUpper not found
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask.
```

I tried without success to add the jars automatically by creating a .hiverc file, and also to modify the `HIVE_AUX_JAR_PATH`.

It would be great to have your help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION myUpper AS 'org.hue.udf.MyUpper';
```

assuming your udf class is called MyUpper in package org.hue.udf